# Is such space monotonically monolithic or strongly monotonically monolithic?

Tags: general-topology

Let $R$ denote the set of all real numbers. $B$ is a subset of $R$ with $B=2^{\aleph_0}$. We topologize $R$ now: the set $B$ is discrete and its complement has the usual topology. So we can see $R$ is the union of a discrete subspace and metrizable space. My question is this:

> Is such space monotonically monolithic or strongly monotonically monolithic?

For the definitions of monotonically monolithic and strongly monotonically monolithic, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297948/what-is-the-relation-between-kappa-monolithic-and-monotonically-monolithic).

Comment: Do you mean to do the construction like the Michael line: the topology is $\mathcal{T}_u \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$, where $\mathcal{T}_u$ is the usual topology?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that such a space has a point-countable base (like the Michael line; use a countable base for the usual topology on $R$ with all singletons from $B$), and all such spaces are monotonically monolithic, according to Tkachuk, "monolithic spaces and D-spaces revisited". The cardinality of $B$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Do you mean that only $B \subset R$ and topologize $R$ as that, then $R$ has point-countable base, and hence strongly monotonically monolithic?

Comment: @Paul yes. I'm not sure whether a point-countable base even gives strongly monotonically monolithic (I only found a reference to monotonically monolithic, as I don't have access to the original paper), but if that's the case, sure. It's pretty clear that *any* space constructed like the Michael line based on a second countable space has a point countable base.

Comment: In the Proposition 2.5 of the same paper of Tkachuk, it said that: If $X$ has a point-countable base then $X$ is strongly monotonically monolithic.